# Paypal Merchant SDK with Laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, paypal, laravel-4

I am trying to create paypal recurring payment profile but i am facing this error

**{"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType' not found","file":"/home/test/public_html/payment/app/models/payment/Purchase.php","line":7}}**

my code

```
<?php

class Purchase extends Eloquent
{
    public static function submit($name, $email, $ccNumber, $pinCode, $expiryDate)
    {
        $profileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType();
        $profileDetails->BillingStartDate = "2014-11-17T00:00:00:000Z";

        $paymentBillingPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType();
        $paymentBillingPeriod->BillingFrequency = 30;
        $paymentBillingPeriod->BillingPeriod = "Day";
        $paymentBillingPeriod->Amount = new BasicAmountType("USD", "1.0");

        $scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType();
        $scheduleDetails->Description = "recurring billing";
        $scheduleDetails->PaymentPeriod = $paymentBillingPeriod;

        $createRPProfileRequestDetails = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType();
        $creditCard = new CreditCardDetailsType();
        $creditCard->CreditCardNumber = "4032034992341100";
        $creditCard->CreditCardType = "Visa";
        $creditCard->CVV2 = "962";
        $creditCard->ExpMonth = 11;
        $creditCard->ExpYear = 2019; 
        $createRPProfileRequestDetails->CreditCard = $creditCard;

        $createRPProfileRequestDetails->ScheduleDetails = $scheduleDetails;
        $createRPProfileRequestDetails->RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails = $profileDetails;

        $createRPProfileRequest = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
        $createRPProfileRequest->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = $createRPProfileRequestDetails;

        $createRPProfileReq = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
        $createRPProfileReq->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest = $createRPProfileRequest;

        $config = array (
            'mode' => Config::get('paypal.mode') , 
            'acct1.UserName' => Config::get('paypal.username'),
            'acct1.Password' => Config::get('paypal.password'), 
            'acct1.Signature' => Config::get('paypal.signature')
        );
        $paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService($config);
        $createRPProfileResponse = $paypalService->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile($createRPProfileReq); 
        die($createRPProfileResponse);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Over the years I've seen lots of struggles with the PayPal SDK's.  That's why I wrote my own years ago, which is now compatible with Composer and much easier to use.  I'd recommend [taking a look at it](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  You can see it used within Laravel within my [PayPal Glass project](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass).  It comes with fully functional samples so you could be up and running in no time.  I know that doesn't answer your question, but it might be quicker than messing with their stuff.

Comment: Is your `RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType` in the same directory as your `Purchase`? If not you need to add the `use ...\RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType; etc`.